# $A$ is onto iff $AA^*$ is bounded below.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am trying to read a paper in which the author claimed the following:

Let $A$ be a bounded linear map from a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ to another Hilbert space  $\mathscr{K}$. The claim is: $A$ is onto if and only if $AA^*$ is bounded below.

I have shown that if $A$ is onto then  $AA^*$ is one-one. So, if $A$ is onto then $AA^*$ has a left inverse. I could not prove that the left inverse is a bounded operator. Also, the reverse direction remains unsolved.

Thank you.

Comment: What is 'bounded below'?

Comment: An operator $B$ is said to be bounded below iff there is a positive $\delta$ such that $\delta ||h||\leq ||Bh||$ for all $h$.

Comment: Did you try the open mapping theorem?

Comment: No, I have not tried open mapping theorem. Please give me some hint.

Comment: OMT implies that $B(0,\varepsilon) \subseteq A(B(0,1))$ for the balls arouns $0$.